# Using Regex to drop period from many column names

Tags: python, regex, pandas, transform

I'd like to drop a '.' from a column name using regex, and want the code to be applied to many column names that end in '.', so that each pair of like-named columns can be merged into one.

For example, the column names 'Fund' and 'Fund.' are different and have different values, but should become just 'Fund'.

What would be the best regex to use for this?

Comment: actually there is no need of regex just `rstrip()` is enough for this

Comment: How the column pairs should be merge if there are values in both column? Can you give a sample please?

Comment: try `df.columns=df.columns.str.rstrip('.')`

Comment: what do you want to happen to the values in the merged columns? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The idea is to get the column names to be the same, and then stack the same-named columns. It is a little tricky because there are many of these pairs and so would rather automate it rather than name them individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=['Fund.'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.','')
```

Output:

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['Fund'], dtype='object')
```